# Windows service unable write into event log

Tags: vb.net, windows-services

I have created the following report service but I am unable to log any thing in the EventLog. In the project settings I have set App Type as windows Service and Startup project as SUB Main... Can any one please suggest whats wrong with the code

Program.vb

```
Imports System.ServiceProcess

    Namespace ReportingService

    Public Class Program
        Private Sub New()
        End Sub
        ''' <summary>The main entry point for the application.</summary>
        Private Shared Sub Main(args As String())
            Dim ServicesToRun As ServiceBase()
            ServicesToRun = New ServiceBase() {
                New ReportingImmediate()
            }
            ServiceBase.Run(ServicesToRun)
        End Sub
    End Class
End Namespace
```

ReportService.vb

```
Imports System.ServiceProcess
Imports System.Timers
Imports System.Configuration

Public Class ReportingImmediate
    Inherits ServiceBase

#Region "Members"

    Private ReadOnly time As Timer
    Private ReadOnly rptHelper As ReportingHelper
    Private ReadOnly timeInterval As String

#End Region

    Public Sub New()
        ' Initialize Logs
        InitializeComponent()
        ' Initialize other components
        time = New Timer()
        timeInterval = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings("ImmediateReRunInterval") '10000
        time.Interval = Integer.Parse(timeInterval)
        AddHandler time.Elapsed, AddressOf TimeElapsed

        rptHelper = New ReportingHelper()
    End Sub

#Region "Timer Event"

    ''' <summary>time Elapsed</summary>
    ''' <param name="sender">The object that raised the event sender</param>
    ''' <param name="e">Event data passed to the handler e</param>
    Private Sub TimeElapsed(sender As Object, e As ElapsedEventArgs)
        time.Enabled = False

        rptHelper.WriteToEventLog("Logging Report Service")

        ' Enable the Timer
        time.Enabled = True
        time.Interval = Integer.Parse(timeInterval)
    End Sub

#End Region

#Region "Service Events"

    ''' <summary>On Start</summary>
    ''' <param name="args">Arguments</param>
    Protected Overrides Sub OnStart(args As String())
        time.Enabled = True
    End Sub

    ''' <summary>On Stop</summary>
    Protected Overrides Sub OnStop()
        time.Enabled = False
    End Sub

#End Region

End Class
```

ReportHelper.vb

```
    Imports System.Data.OleDb
    Imports System.Configuration
    Imports System.Threading.Tasks
    Imports System.IO
    Imports System.IO.Packaging
    Imports System.Text
    Imports System.Net.Mail
    Imports System.Net

    Public Class ReportingHelper

        Public Function WriteToEventLog(ByVal entry As String, Optional ByVal appName As String = "ReportingService", Optional ByVal eventType As  _
                            EventLogEntryType = EventLogEntryType.Information, Optional ByVal logName As String = "RepotingServiceImmediate") As Boolean

        Dim objEventLog As New EventLog

        Try

            'Register the Application as an Event Source
            If Not EventLog.SourceExists(appName) Then
                EventLog.CreateEventSource(appName, logName)
            End If

            'log the entry
            objEventLog.Source = appName
            objEventLog.WriteEntry(entry, eventType)

            Return True

        Catch Ex As Exception

            Return False

        End Try

    End Function
End Class
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your service will not be able to `EventLog.CreateEventSource` because it does not run as an administrator (ref: the Note in the Remarks section of [EventLog.CreateEventSource Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5zbwd3s3.aspx)):

> To create an event source in Windows Vista and later or Windows Server 2003, you must have administrative privileges.
>
> The reason for this requirement is that all event logs, including security, must be searched to determine whether the event source is unique. Starting with Windows Vista, users do not have permission to access the security log; therefore, a SecurityException is thrown.

As you should not run your service as an administrator, the solution is to write a small  program which you run with Administrator privileges to create the event source.

The `Try...Catch` in `DWPReportingHelper.WriteToEventLog` may be hiding an error from you.

Comment: Since you also need administrator privilege in order to install a service, it is probably sensible to create the event source at the same time.

Comment: I am installing the service using admin privilege but the only entry in the event log is service started successfully and stopped successfully and I am not writing it. I tried directly creating log inside new and timer event of ReportService.VB file but nothing happens...

Comment: @NikhilGupta Try using an existing log, e.g. use `logName = "Application"`.

Comment: I solved it using following Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\EventLog\Application\App_Name]

Comment: Just as an addendum, you do not need to be an admin to write to the Windows event logs but you will need to be granted permission which requires you to edit the ACL (Access Control List) using wevtutil. [This question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5500718/windows-event-log-access-from-ssis-package-run-in-sql-agent-job) can lead you in the right direction if you decide to not make everything run as admin (and really you shouldn't on the whole).